# Sublime Text 4 Center View

Tags: sublimetext4

Is there any way to center the code view in sublime text 4 without going full screen?  Distraction free mode centers the text but it removes line numbers and puts the application in full screen mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set the following preference to have text always centered, even when not in distraction free mode:

```json
    // Draws text centered in the window rather than left aligned
    "draw_centered": true,
```